# PrimeFaces Push 5.0 with Wildfly 8.1 not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, atmosphere, primepush

I'm planning to start using PrimeFaces Push coming with PrimeFaces 5.0. 
I've tried to run the same example found here http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml using Wildfly 8.1 but I can't receive any push message from backend bean.

Here is what I've on wildfly console :

> 01:50:34,926 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (Thread-261) Latest version of Atmosphere's JavaScript Client 2.2.2
>   01:50:34,926 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (Thread-261)
>
> Current version of Atmosphere 2.2.0-RC3 
>     Newest version of Atmosphere available 2.1.7
>
> 01:50:37,447 ERROR [org.atmosphere.interceptor.JavaScriptProtocol] (default task-61) Invalid Atmosphere Version 2.2.0-javascript
>   01:50:37,448 WARN  [org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol] (default task-61) Status code higher or equal than 400 Status 501 Message OK
>   01:50:41,957 INFO  [stdout] (default task-62) sending message
>
> 01:55:37,760 ERROR [org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor] (default task-63) Failed to cancel resource: 8cf3d711-00c2-4e52-9d78-97cd04c0b585: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointHandlerProxy.onStateChange(PushEndpointHandlerProxy.java:241) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
>     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.invokeAtmosphereHandler(AsynchronousProcessor.java:492) [atmosphere-runtime-2.2.0-RC3.jar:2.2.0-RC3]
>     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.completeLifecycle(AsynchronousProcessor.java:444) [atmosphere-runtime-2.2.0-RC3.jar:2.2.0-RC3]
>     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.endRequest(AsynchronousProcessor.java:548) [atmosphere-runtime-2.2.0-RC3.jar:2.2.0-RC3]
>     at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.executeClose(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:676) [atmosphere-runtime-2.2.0-RC3.jar:2.2.0-RC3]
>     at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.close(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:628) [atmosphere-runtime-2.2.0-RC3.jar:2.2.0-RC3]
>     at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint.onClose(JSR356Endpoint.java:221) [atmosphere-runtime-2.2.0-RC3.jar:2.2.0-RC3]
>     at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.UndertowSession.close(UndertowSession.java:181) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>     at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.UndertowSession.close(UndertowSession.java:171) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>     at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.FrameHandler$1.run(FrameHandler.java:93) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>     at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer$1.run(ServerWebSocketContainer.java:303) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>     at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.OrderedExecutor$ExecutorTask.run(OrderedExecutor.java:49) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]

Here is my web.xml configuration for PrimeFaces push:

> ```
>    <context-param>
>            <param-name>primefaces.PUSH_SERVER_URL</param-name>
>            <param-value>http://127.0.0.1:8080</param-value>
>    </context-param>
>
>    <servlet>
>            <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
>            <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
>            <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
>            <async-supported>true</async-supported>
>    </servlet>
>
>    <servlet-mapping>
>            <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
>            <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
>    </servlet-mapping>
> ```

I appreciate your help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem using Primefaces 5.0 and Atmosphere Runtime 2.2.0.

Solved it, by changing to Atmosphere 2.1.7 (which is still the newest version according to log output). Now push messages work fine...

Comment: Yes, I found that this is the issue but I forgot to update my answer (Thanks). One issue still exists because I'm running my application on Wildfly 8.1 which is the Websockets support. it need upgraded version of Push.js file on PrimeFaces library.

Comment: PF 5.0 + Glassfish 4, and downgrading Atmosphere from 2.2.3 to 2.1.7 still solves the problem. Thank you!